# Emacs Per File Customization

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an Emacs Lisp file with custom macros I want fontified and indented differently.  The code looks like:

```
(defmacro* when-let ((var value) &rest body)
  `(let ((,var ,value))
     (when ,var ,@body)))

(defun func ()
  (when-let (a 1)
    a))
```

I want `when-let` fontified as a `font-lock-keyword` and indented as above.  I know I can do this in my .emacs file but I'd prefer to make it a directory local or file local customization.  The problem is that directory local and file local customizations seem to be limited to setting variables.  In my .emacs file I have the following.

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
             (put 'when-let 'lisp-indent-function 1)
             (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                                     '(("(\\(when-let\\)\\>" 1
                                        font-lock-keyword-face)))))
```

I want this in `.dir-locals.el` because it applies only to one file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify elisp for evaluation in *file local variables<sup>1</sup>* by specifying an `eval:` value (the documentation says 'Eval:' but only lower-case 'eval:' seems to work). e.g.:

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; mode: outline-minor
;;; eval: (hide-body)
;;; End:
```

As a security measure, Emacs will ask you for confirmation whenever it sees a value it does not already recognise as safe. If you tell it to remember it permanently, it writes the value to `safe-local-variable-values` in the `(custom-set-variables)` section of your init file.

Note that the above example of enabling a minor mode is deprecated (the `mode` local variable is for major modes only), so we need to re-write it as another evaluated form, in which we call the minor mode function.

If you need to evaluate multiple forms, you can either specify multiple `eval` values, which will be evaluated in order:

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; eval: (outline-minor-mode 1)
;;; eval: (hide-body)
;;; End:
```

Or alternatively, just use progn:

```
;;; Local Variables:
;;; eval: (progn (outline-minor-mode 1) (hide-body))
;;; End:
```

The difference is that the latter would be considered a single value for the purposes of `safe-local-variable-values`, whereas with multiple `eval` values each one is considered independently.

<sup>1</sup> <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) File Local Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: As a bit of clarification, the above code blocks should go at the top of the file(s) you want it to apply to.  This will work for any type of file, as long as it appears in the file's language as a comment (e.g. in a C++ file, the ;;; could be replaced with //).

Comment: I expect it can go anywhere, but it's more typical to place a local variables block like this at the very *end* of a file. File-local variables at the *top* of a file invariably use the other syntax (see `C-h i g` `(emacs) Specifying File Variables` `RET`).

Answer (score 3):

For identing your when-let macro, you could use the indent declaration:

```
(defmacro* when-let ((var value) &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(let ((,var ,value))
     (when ,var ,@body)))
```

look at the info node `(elisp)Indenting Macros` for more information about this.
I don't know about a similar things for fontification.